# Link own queries symfony2 repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to factorize some code in my models repositories.

A really basic example

```
public function getPlayers()
{  
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->innerJoin(...) // whatever the request
        ->where(...)
        // I want to factorize this line because a lot of function use it 
        ->andWhere('p.active = true'); 
    return (...);
}
```

So I create a private function

```
private function getActivePlayer() {
    return $this->andWhere('p.active = true');
}
```

And I would like to use it like that in any function

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->innerJoin(...)
            ->where(...)
            ->getActivePlayer()
```

But of course I have this error

```
Attempted to call method "getActivePlayer" on class "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder"
```

It's possible to achieve this kind of factorization? What will be the syntaxe?

Thanks

Comment: Should `->getPlayerType()` be `getActivePlayer()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
public function getPlayers()
{  
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->innerJoin(...)
        ->where(...);
    $qb = $this->getPlayerType($qb);
}

private function getActivePlayer(QueryBuilder $qb)
{
    return $qb->andWhere('p.active = true');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `->` operator in the context of a `QueryBuilder` object will only call methods within the `QueryBuilder` class. You must define your own class that extends the `QueryBuilder`. Something like:

```
class MyQueryBuilder extends \Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder {
    public function getActivePlayer() {
        return $this->andWhere('p.active = true');
    }
}
```

Then implement that builder instead of the default Query Builder:

```
$qb = new MyQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('p')
    ->from(...)
    ->innerJoin(...)
    ->where(...)
    ->getActivePlayer()
    // ...
```

Note that the above code is just simple demonstration to show you what length of effort it takes to achieve exactly what you want to do - in actual practice, you'll need to do more than this.

You are best off starting with a basic QueryBuilder in a particular private method then amending it in your public getters:

```
private function getPlayerQueryBuilder()
{  
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->innerJoin(...) // whatever the request
        ->where(...)
    return $qb;
}

public function getActivePlayers() {
    $result = $this->getPlayerQueryBuilder()
        ->andWhere('p.active = true')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $result;
}

public function getAllPlayers() {
    $result = $this->getPlayerQueryBuilder()
        ->getQuery()->getResult();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Especially since what you posted won't actually work.

Comment: @Cerad Exactly why I said it. My answer is a dumbed-down version of the basics of what needs to be done, but it's way more involved than this.

Comment: I've presented a better alternative, so hopefully that will work better for OP.